# How can i restore original select option values on ajax success?

Tags: jquery, ajax

I am changing select option values to its label text on ajax form submission but i want to reset it back to its original value on ajax success.

Here is how i am modifying the select on submission.

```
  jQuery("select option").val(function(){
    return $(this).text();
  });
```

P.S i can't use location.reload();

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could store the values using [`.data()`](https://api.jquery.com/data/) and then restore them back when you need to.

Sample (without the actual ajax call, but should give you the idea):

```js
$(function() {
  $('form').on('submit', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    
    var $options = $(this).find('select option');
    
    $options.val(function () {
      $(this).data('value', $(this).val());
      return $(this).text();
    });
    
    console.log($options.eq(0).val());
    console.log($options.eq(1).val());
    
    // ... Ajax stuff goes here ...
    
    // On ajax success:
    $options.val(function () {
      return $(this).data('value');
    });
    
    console.log($options.eq(0).val());
    console.log($options.eq(1).val());
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<form>
  <select>
    <option value="1">one</option>
    <option value="2">two</option>
  </select>
  
  <button>submit</button>
</form>
```

Unrelated note: it's generally recommended to use more specific selectors than that. You can use classes, but I suggest using `data-` attributes themselves as selectors (that leaves classes for CSS).

Comment: Excellent, Thanks :-)